# In Computer Directory find file inside folder even if hidden by cmd

Tags: windows, file, cmd, directory

I am trying to find file inside my PC's directory even if it is hidden. Some hidden files are creating problems. And they are in each and every folder in my project folder. I want to delete them. But delete each and every of them by going to those folders will kill my whole day. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is command to find specific file in each and every folder .... but at first you need to go to the folder and open cmd from that folder... then execute the command to see the files are there or not.

dir *filename.extension /a:h /S

After Command execute , you will see that file is exist or not. If you are sure that these are the files, than if you wish to delete it, execute the command bellow ,

del *filename.extension /a:h /S

Here "dir" means you want to see directories. "del" means you want to delete it.
/a:h means you want to show if it is hidden, if file is not hidden, you can skip it.
/S means, if file is in subfolders, it will bring it out.